# using variables for unit testing only

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, unit-testing, ios

I am writing unit tests for an app for iPhone using objective c.
I want to use some variable only when compiling for test case for example

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING 
@synthesize requestFinished, networkAvailable;//etc
#endif
```

now where should I define UNIT_TESTING that when I compile for unit tests it should enter this code block.... otherwise should go past it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define it in the “Preprocessor Macros” build setting in each of your targets—especially the one where you want that macro defined, the unit test bundle target.

Comment: What if the project I want to write unit tests for depends on a static library which I need to use these macros in? The ifdef is never defined since the library is already compiled, no?

Comment: @Genericrich: Right. You would need to define the macros in the library's target when building the library. If you need to use the macros in both places, put them in a header and import that from the prefix headers of both targets.