# Cocoa Unit Testing - App is launching before tests

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, unit-testing, xctest

When launching unit tests (XCTest) in Xcode 5 for a Mac Cocoa app, it starts the app before launching the tests.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

---

**Just a little side note:**

I've found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714697/unit-testing-in-xcode-does-it-run-the-app) which seems to be pretty similar to what I need... That question is for iOS instead, I want to solve this for Mac OS X.

The problem is it is using `UIApplicationMain` which is to my knowledge for iOS. For OSX, I don't believe there is a way to switch app delegate like that with `NSApplicationMain`.

Comment: See [XCode 5 unit testing: starts my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219706/xcode-5-unit-testing-starts-my-app).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't expect to have some settings for this.

Comment: My question is a duplicate then... I'll vote to close this.