# Is there any way to run unit tests in Xcode without building and launching the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I'm in a very early stage of developing an iOS application, and right now, I just want to test the logic of my Swift code. I don't care about the actual app yet. I've written some unit tests in my tests file, but whenever I run the test suite, it launches the simulator with an iPod Touch as the target device, even though it has nothing to do with my tests for now. Is there a way to disable that?

I've tried going to **Project > General** and setting the Host Application to 'None' for tests, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. And I don't know if this is relevant but I also turned off AuthenticationUITests under **Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219706/xcode-5-unit-testing-starts-my-app) was the most relevant post I could come across regarding this topic, but it seems to be outdated because I can't find Bundle Loader and Test Host in that place anymore.

I also tried using xctool as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134670/dont-launch-simulator-when-running-unittests) post, but when I try `brew install xctool`, it says:

```
Warning: xctool has been deprecated because it has an archived upstream repository!
Error: xctool: no bottle available!
```