# Why some functions coverage is already 100% xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I recently started to write tests for my project. after writing a few amount of tests i realized in coverage section some of my classes or functions has **coverage** more than 50%(like **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** func in **AppDelegate**) without that i wrote any test for them.
where this coverage comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the tests are running, they are starting your app. That means they are using your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` runs, including all methods that are called from it.

If a method runs, its coverage is calculated. If there is no branching, the coverage will be 100%.

Related: [Unit Testing in Xcode, does it run the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714697/unit-testing-in-xcode-does-it-run-the-app/15725328#15725328)
Basically, you can inject an empty application delegate when testing to avoid this kind of behavior.

Comment: so there is same logic for functions like viewDidAppear in view controller?

Comment: @MohammadKhakpaki . I don't get your question. I am telling you that unit tests basically start you app and then they are running the unit tests inside it.

Comment: i understood you. my next question is this situation(100% coverage ) is also happening for functions like viewDidAppear in viewControllers. Do you think this behavior reason is same as above that you told?

Comment: @MohammadKhakpaki Yes. The app delegate normally instantiates the root controller and shows it on the screen. It's the same as when you start your app normally but you don't touch the screen at all.

Comment: I use a different app delegate when running tests: https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/